# Is it possible to create a custom event for calendar similar to tasks add on in calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-app-maker, custom-events, google-tasks

I am a beginner with Google App maker. I want a custom calendar event similar to 'outOfOffice'/AppointmentSlots'. I used the tasks add on there is a new event type called 'Task' appearing when I try to create an event. [image]

Also, There are new interactions with a task event type

[image]

I would like to create a new event type similar to tasks and new interactions when the event is clicked on. I am hoping that AppMaker would help me achive this. I did not find any api support in Google calendar for creating a new event type. Please advise

Comment: Nope. I don't think so there is any API available for this. Appmaker also won't add much value as it is mostly dependant on these APIs.